# Why Xsd parsing is failing for specific attribute, if there is a corresponding xml namespace available in Go?

Tags: go, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a generated xsd via golang. To keep it very simple for this use case, the xsd schema contains only an enum(simpletype).

Sample code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

var schemaStr = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.web.com/MYSVC" xmlns:svc="http://schemas.web.com/MYSVCC" xmlns:codegen="http://schemas.web.com/MYSVC" targetNamespace="http://schemas.web.com/MYSVC" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:simpleType name="My_Enum_e">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
      <xsd:enumeration value="0" codegen:cname="ENUM_0" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="1" codegen:cname="ENUM_1" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="2" codegen:cname="ENUM_2" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="3" codegen:cname="ENUM_3" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>`

type Schema struct {
    XMLName         xml.Name          `xml:"schema"`
    TargetNamespace string            `xml:"targetNamespace,attr"`
    Namespaces      map[string]string `xml:"-"`
    SimpleTypes     []*SimpleType     `xml:"simpleType"`
}

type SimpleType struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name     `xml:"simpleType"`
    Name        string       `xml:"name,attr"`
    Restriction *Restriction `xml:"restriction"`
}

type Restriction struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"restriction"`
    Base    string   `xml:"base,attr"`
    Enum    []*Enum  `xml:"enumeration"`
}

type Enum struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"enumeration"`
    Value      string   `xml:"value,attr"`
    EnumString string   `xml:"codegen cname,attr"`
}

func main() {
    schema := &Schema{}
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(schemaStr), schema)
    for _, simpleType := range schema.SimpleTypes {
        if simpleType.Restriction == nil {
            continue
        }
        for _, enumVal := range simpleType.Restriction.Enum {
            fmt.Printf("[%v] = [%v]\n", enumVal.Value, enumVal.EnumString)
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the above program is [Go Play link replicating the issue](https://play.golang.org/p/KVuXyEtHEoX)

```
[0] = []
[1] = []
[2] = []
[3] = []
```

It is not able to parse the codegen:cname tags available as part of the xsd.
If I manually remove the following xml namespace

```
xmlns:codegen="http://schemas.web.com/MYSVC"
```

then I am getting the expected output as below [Go Play link after removing codegen namespace](https://play.golang.org/p/wDBzAzS72jl)

```
[0] = [ENUM_0]
[1] = [ENUM_1]
[2] = [ENUM_2]
[3] = [ENUM_3]
```

Need help in understanding the difference in behavior with and without having the namespace when parsing it in go ?. Is there any way where I can get the EnumStrings ENUM_0...3 without modifying the original xsd file which I am parsing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace is `http://schemas.web.com/MYSVC`, `codegen` is an alias of the namespace, which is lost once the XML is parsed:

```
EnumString string   `xml:"http://schemas.web.com/MYSVC cname,attr"`
```